# VersionControl multiple merge c#

Tags: c#, merge

I developed a simple C# windows application to help me when I have to merge changesets from a source branch to another.

I was also trying to implement multiple merge by selecting more changesets and merging them inside an iteration.

It's basically working ( the files in the destination branch are correctly updated ) but when I get the updated list of Merge Candidates from the source branch It still gives me those changesets. This doens't happen when I merge a single Changeset.

Do you know if there are better ways to make multiple merges?

Here I report some code for you:

```
Workspace ws = versionControl.GetWorkspace(config.WorkingFolder);

foreach(string changesetId in candidates){
ChangesetVersionSpec csvs = new ChangesetVersionSpec(changesetId);
        GetStatus gs = ws.Merge(config.SourceBranchPath, config.DestinationBranchPath, csvs, csvs, LockLevel.None, RecursionType.Full, MergeOptions.None);
}
```